# DbContext string constructor longer than 128 chars

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm creating a DB using entityFramework and SQLCompact. I'm trying to create a new DB file using a path that sometimes is longer than 128 chars and I get an exception when this happen.

> The value's length for key 'initial catalog' exceeds it's limit of
>   '128'.

Is there anyway to change this behavior and use a connection string longer than that?

```
public class DbTestingContext: DbContext
{

    public DbTestingContext() : base(GetConnectionString())
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DbTestingContext>());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TestingModel> Tests { get; set; }

    private static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "/db/",
            "TestingPrototypes.DbTests.DbTestsContext.sdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `GetConnectionString` is doing what you think it's doing, that will return the **path** to your `.sdf` file, not a valid connection string

Comment: isn't the `connectionString` required by the `Dbcontext` just a `name` in the webConfig that is used to fetch its `connectionString` value? you can name the key what ever want but the `connectionString` attribute is where you put all the DB related stuff..

Comment: @Liam When I call base(GetConnectionString()) it's suppose to create the DB file in the string path if it doesn't exist, but sometimes that path is longer than 128 chars and I get an exception

Comment: Shorten the path? :D Maybe you can create an [NTFS hard link](http://superuser.com/questions/746325/how-to-create-a-hard-link-in-windows-using-mklink-command) which should work as long as you don't cross file system boundaries

Comment: The overload for DbContext that accepts a string expects a connection string, not a path [`public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it. The problem was that despite of the fact that I have installed and coded everything I forgot to change the default connection to the DB and I was using the internal one that provides VS2015.

Once I changed it to use SQLCompact that exception which was trhown with 128 chars in connection string has dissapeared and when is accessing to the path if the DB does not exist it creates one new.

Change App.config

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

To this one:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```